# Can I create an interactive list that displays only one sublist at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, menu

for my website, I'm trying to create a list of artists. when a user clicks the name I want to display a list of tracks. when the user clicks on a track, a video displays. Is this possible in HTML? I know very little js. I've spent a few hours on this and haven't been able to get anything working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lets see what have you tried.

Comment: @drip i just gave up and deleted my attempts. all i have now is a long list with no formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with AJAX.

Let's say you have such HTML code:

```
<div id="artists">
    <div class="artist" data-art-id="1">Artist name 1</div>
    <div class="artist" data-art-id="2">Artist name 2</div>
    <div class="artist" data-art-id="3">Artist name 3</div>
</div>
<div id="tracks"></div>
<div id="video"></div>
```

Then you have to white jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.artist').click(function() {
        var artId = $(this).attr('data-art-id');
        $('#tracks').load('/get_tracks_list.php?art_id=' + artId, function() {
            $('.track').click(function() {
                var trackId = $(this).attr('data-track-id');
                $('#video').load('/get_video.php?track_id=' + trackId);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Your `get_tracks_list.php` should have something like this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect(YOUR_HOST, YOUR_LOGIN, YOUR_PASS);
mysql_select_db(YOUR_DB);

$artId = intval($_GET['art_id']);   //prevent SQL injection
$res = mysql_query('SELECT track_id, track_name FROM tracks WHERE art_id="'.$artId.'"');
while ($track = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo '<div class="track" data-track-id="'.$track['track_id'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($track['track_name']).'</div>';
}
```

And `get_video.php` should contain information about the video.

This approach requires that you have all your data in DB (table names and field names may be different)

I think this is the most common practice.

Good luck!